# How to unwind and jump directly to the destination View Controller

Tags: xcode, unwind-segue

I have three View Controllers. VC1 is embedded in a UINavigationController and the other two are accessible via Push Segues, so they are on the Navigation Stack.  I've created an Unwind Segue to jump back from VC3 to VC1.  The issue is when the unwind segue is triggered, it pushes to VC2 and pushed to VC1. Although this happens quickly, I would prefer if it just went to VC1 directly.  Is this possible?

Comment: So basically you want to skip VC2 in the navigation stack on the way back from VC3. Right?

Comment: Yes.  I want to go from VC3 to VC1 directly.  Currently it pushes through VC2 first and then moves to VC1.  The action that I'm using to call the Unwind is viewWillDisappear() on VC3, when the user presses the back button in the Navigation Bar (not sure if this is relevant to you).

Comment: You have some options, I would say subclassing of UINavigationControllerDelegate might work the best. You can fiddle around UIController transition behaviour. I can post some example if you want, but only how to make some basic stuff.

Comment: Vanya.  I think I will leave the behavior the way it is.  I have many other issues that are higher priority.  Thanks very much for your help though!