# iOS swift unwind 2 view controllers and show another one

Tags: ios, swift, segue, unwind-segue

I have 4 View Controllers (A, B ,C ,D). I can go from A -> B , B -> C. In the View Controller C what I want to do, Remove the B and C then show view controller D. so that If I go back from D it goes to A.

I want to perform this with a transition smoothly. D already has a UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate methods implemented. So in C I should be able to remove itself and B then show D with the D's Transition like nothing happened. I am not using a NavigationController. What are the approaches I can use to do this ?

Im using Xcode 9 and Swift 4
Thanks

Comment: I have already tried unwinding to A and presenting D in unwind method in A, but it says that A is not in the Window Hierarchy yet

Comment: I had the same issue, but was not able to resolve it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46054177/how-to-unwind-and-jump-directly-to-the-destination-view-controller

Comment: I think in ur case the solution is to use an unwind segue. maybe this would help. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=akmPXZ4hDuU

Comment: Is A is your window root view controller??

Comment: Yes its the Root VC

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the viewControllers are under the same UINavigationController, why don't you try to use the `setViewControllers:animated:` method of the navigationController and set the array to be [viewControllerA],

or `popToViewController:animated:` and pass in the viewController A,

or assuming the VC A is the root VC, use 
 `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` to pop to the root.

Hope this helps

Comment: unfortunately I am not using a navigation controller. Is it possible to use a navigation controller without showing navigation bar ontop of the view?

Comment: Yes, use the `isNavigationBarHidden` property or `setNavigationBarHidden(_:animated:)` method in the UINavigationController

Answer (score 0):

since I couldn't find a way to remove the VC s below D. I went to another approach. When Ds Segue finished (finished transition from C) I cleaned the B and Cs resources. this freed up memory. so That is the workaround I found.

And when I unwind from D to A all the VCs above A is removed automatically